# Create Controller and add Views to another project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Visual Studio 2015 + all updates.
Asp .Net Web application (MVC).

I start off by adding a few class libraries and separating the Asp .Net WA into layers i.e. DataAccess, Business Logic and the web project itself.

Once separated I add relevant references and everything is working as I expect it to be (i.e. the application functions as it did before I separated it into layers).

In my BL (Controllers are found here). I don't have the option to Add a Controller, like you would when right clicking the Controllers folder in the default project, so add the below line

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

to the csproj file for my class library and the Add Controller option now appears. Create a controller but throws an error which was due to not having a web.config file - add this file and all works (although it would be nice to have this library working without a web.config file).

The problem I've hit is, when the Controller is created it also adds a View template within the class library but my Views folder is located in my web project.

Have I done this wrong? Is there a workaround so when a controller is created, it also creates the Views into the correct project? Or another approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but it seems like you are try to use a UI-based architectural pattern to build your business layer.

Typically, your models, views, and controllers are all maintained in the main web-app project. Any supporting functions (like your BL and DL) are added via class libraries. The Visual Studio MVC templates are built around that concept, which is why you had to manually add support with the GUID - and why it automatically creates the view.

If I may ask, why are you trying to build controllers into your BL? If you are trying to decouple your UI from your server code, perhaps WebAPI would be a better option.

**UPDATE - A few helpful links**

[ProDinner - ASP.NET MVC Sample App](https://prodinner.codeplex.com/)

[N Layered App with Entity Framework, Autofac, ASP.NET MVC and Unit Testing](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Service-Layer-Entity-7a1fac6c)

[Architecture Guide: ASP.NET MVC Framework + N-tier + Entity Framework and Many More](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En)

Comment: Hmm I thought this was the correct approach? The thought i had, was to move the controllers to the BL so everything was in one place.... i assume your suggesting leaving the controllers within the main web project and import the BL/DA dll into the project using these as a reference for any CRUD operations? Any examples/advice i could follow to try this out if ive understood you correctly? Thx

Comment: That's correct. The web app is the MVC portion of your solution. All of your models, view, and controllers reside here. Your BL or Domain logic would/could be a separate DLL. And, your DL or Data Context would be another DLL. The point of MVC is to keep business logic out of you those components and allow your controllers to interact with the other layers for logic and data. I'll update my answer with a few links that may help.

Comment: Thanks. I will go through the links as the next part i was looking to introduce was the DataContext....

Answer (score 1):

Most of your issues boil down to using the scaffold. The scaffold is great when you're just starting out or for extremely simple projects, but it quickly falls down beyond that. Specifically, adding a controller via scaffold is designed for an MVC project, so it expects to find things you'd find in an MVC project. Additionally, it creates scaffolded views in an appropriate directory in `Views` because, again, that's what it's designed to do.

The simplest solution, then, is to just not use the scaffolds. A controller is just a class that inherits from `Controller`. Nothing special there. Then, you can create the views where you want to create them.